# XML to .txt using python

Tags: python

I have written code based on a txt file but in production it will be an XML file. I need to be able to iterate over **every single character** in an XML file as if it were a standard text file.

I have the below as an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<openBranchData>
<phoneSwMngmtEnabled/>
-<phoneSwMngmtData>
<imgProvisioningEnabled/>
<startTime>02:00</startTime>
<stopTime>06:00</stopTime>
<centralPhoneSwServer/>
<maxParallelAccess>3</maxParallelAccess>
<phoneSwPullingEnabled/>
</phoneSwMngmtData>
<voiceMailEnabled/>
```

I've tried the below `python` code.

```
with open('osb_file.xml') as test:
    testing = test.read()

for x in testing:
    print(x)
```

Do I need to convert to a `txt` file or is there a simpler way? It's been a while since I've looked at this project so apologies if I'm missing anything very obvious.

Comment: XML files are already text files.  Read them like you would read any other text file.

Comment: Lol thanks I thought that might be the case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As [Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) said, XML files are already text files. You can read them just like you read a standard text file in python using `open(filename, 'r')`